# ruby on rails gravatar_image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gravatar

I am following the railstutorial.org tutorial. While I am able to see the gravatar on the webpage, my rspec test is failing.

Here is the user_controller_spec.rb test:

```
describe "GET 'show'" do

  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory(:user)
  end

  it "should be successful" do
    get :show, :id => @user
    response.should be_success
  end

end
```

Here is the relevant show.html.erb file:

```
<table class="profile" summary="Profile information">
  <tr>
    <td class="main">
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_image_tag(@user.email) %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </td>
    <td class="sidebar round">
      <strong>Name</strong> <%= @user.name %><br />
      <strong>URL</strong> <%= link_to user_path(@user), @user %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I get an error stating "undefined method 'gravatar_image_tag'. I already installed the corresponding gem by executing "gem install gravatar_image_tag", added it to my gemfile, and also executed "bundle install". It is listed as installed when I execute "gem list"

I have been trying to debug this for several hours now. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. BTW, I'm running 32-bit Windows 7 with GIT Bash, RubyInstaller-1.9.2-p0.

Error message:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `gravatar_image_tag` gem global to all environments in your gemfile?  If you have it in a `group :development, :production` block, or something similar, it wouldn't be available in test.

And I haven't tried it, but your line:

`get :show, :id => @user`

seems like it needs to be:

`get :show, :id => @user.id`

Comment: Thanks man!!! That was the issue. I had the gravatar_image_tag gem in the development group!!! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: also get :show, :id => @user
and get :show, :id => @user.id are identical

Answer (score 18):

Following the same tutorial, I had the same `undefined method 'gravatar_image_tag'` error, but a different solution from the accepted one above (my gem was in the correct place in the Gemfile, so that wasn't the problem).

Just had to restart the server  (`Ctrl C` then `rails server`), and then everything was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the gem.  Can you open an issue on the github page http://github.com/mdeering/gravatar_image_tag/issues with the version of rails and a gem list for me.  I will see if I can resolve the issue for you and post an answer back here.

I have some pre-release versions of the gem that I could push out to gemcutter that might resolve the issue already.

Cheers,
Mike D.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spork as DRB server try to restart it, that helped me! (i'm also following Hartls PDF).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, a simple restart fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The gravatar gem file has been updated since the release of Michael Hartl's PDF.

```
gem 'gravatar_image_tag'
```

Include that in your Gemfile and then restart your rails server using

```
rails s
```

That worked for me.